# Integrate apache subversion with the active directory in windows server

Tags: apache, svn, active-directory

Initially I have installed apache server 2.4 in windows server 2012 R2 and i have installed apache subversion 1.8.7 and i have copied module files(.so files) from subversion to apache server.I have created a repository. I have setup the "AuthUserFile" and  "AuthzSVNAccessFile" I have given following code in httpd.conf

```html
<Location /project1>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath E:\svn_testing\project1

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Project1 repository"
  AuthUserFile c:/etc/svn-auth-file

  Require valid-user

  AuthzSVNAccessFile c:/etc/svn-acl
</Location>
```

I have used tortoise svn client to connect to repository which i have successfully connected I have successfully created files,commit the files.
Later i want to setup authentication with the active directory I have added following code in http.conf file

```html
<Location /project1>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath E:\svn_testing\project1
  SVNParentPath E:\svn_testing
  SVNListparentPath on
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  #AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  AuthName "Active_directory_integration"
  AuthzSVNAccessFile C:\etc\svn-acl

  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://***********(ip address):389/DC=*******,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"

  #this assumes you have created a dedicated bind user "apache_bind" on your active directory
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=users,DC=*******,DC=com"

  #warning: this password for AD apache_bind user is in plain text!
  AuthLDAPBindPassword *************

  #AuthLDAPFollowReferrals off
  
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
  AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
  #SSLRequireSSL
  require ldap-group OU=********,DC=********,DC=com
  #require valid-user
</Location>
```

But when i try to restart the server apache server it is showing "The Requested operation has failed" I have checked the log files but there is nothing there

Comment: Have you tried VisualSVN Server? Active Directory integration works out of the box with the server even in free Standard Edition. See https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#Authentication-Settings and https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#User-Permissions

Comment: But VisualSVN is a paid version. that's why i have tried apache subversion

Comment: The free Standard Edition supports AD integration. Just try it. :)

Comment: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/

Comment: Nikhilesh, the conf files in your question show that you are trying to configure Basic Windows authentication for your AD domain accounts. VisualSVN Server Standard Edition supports this out of the box. You should be able to install the server in less than 5 minutes and enable AD integration just in a few clicks. See the Getting Started guide at https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#Authentication-Settings PS I'm with VisualSVN Team and it seems to me that the server is exactly what you are looking for. Download and run the installer to see it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you are trying to search the whole AD-Catalog, as you do not specify any OU. this is not supported by Windows AD. However the whole Catalog is available by using port `3268` 
Please try this:

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://***********(ip address):3268/DC=*******,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member    
require ldap-group OU=********,DC=********,DC=com
```

Organizational Units (ou) dont have the attribute `member`, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683886(v=vs.85).aspx.

You should try the DN of the group you want to access your repo.

On my server this would look like this:

```
require ldap-group cn=thegroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

Notice the cn, which is a `groupOfNames` with the `member` attribute in my case.